# Wrap React Semantic-UI Menu.Item in anchor tag without ruining it styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I have a React Semantic Ui menu which has to link to another page.
I am trying to wrap it with an anchor tag, but this completely breaks the styles on the menu buttons. I would like to think I'm doing something wrong before assuming it's a but.

This is what my code currently looks like:

```
<Menu tabular attached='top'>
   <a href={item1Url}><Menu.Item link>item1</Menu.Item></a>
   <a href={item2Url}><Menu.Item active link>Item 2</Menu.Item></a>
</Menu>
```

Before wrapping the `Menu.Item` with the `a` tag, this is what it currently looked like:

[image]

With the `a` tag wrapping it, it looks like this:

[image]

Not to mention that it disappears completely when I hover on it. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the doc](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/menu/#content-link-item), you can directly add the `href` (and `target`) attributes to the `Menu.Item` element.

In your case the result would be:

```
<Menu tabular attached='top'>
   <Menu.Item href="item1Url">item1</Menu.Item></a>
   <Menu.Item href="item2Url"active>Item 2</Menu.Item></a>
</Menu>
```

Comment: Ended up finding that out after posting the question, I guess I am completely out of date. Thanks!